# Merge first n commits of branch to master

Tags: git, merge, fast-forward

I have a branch from the most recent commit to `master`. the branch has two commits on it. I'd like to fast-forward merge the *first* of those commits onto master.

I know I could do a cherry pick, but I don't really want to diverge the master and branch if I can help it.

Current state:

```
Branch:       +--->B--->C
             /
Master: --->A
```

Cherry-pick option:

```
Branch:       +--->B--->C
             /
Master: --->A--->B'
```

Ideal option:

```
Branch:            +--->C
                  /
Master: --->A--->B
```

Is this possible?

Note that the commits are all pushed to the remote already; but no-one else currently has access to this particular repo so a `push -f` would be OK.

I seem to remember there might be some way to merge onto master while a branch is checked out... if that is true, I could simply check out commit B, then merge in that manner?

Comment: From master `git merge B`.

Comment: @RaymondChen damn, I'm an idiot. If you'd like to make that an answer I can accept it and it might help others similarly struck by the 3-O-clockses?

Comment: Go ahead and answer your own question and accept it.I don't need the imaginary points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More specifically, you might want:

```
git merge --ff-only <commit-specifier>
```

which tells Git to do a fast-forward not-really-a-merge of the current branch, whatever that is, to the specified commit.  Such an operation:

1. tests whether `HEAD` is an ancestor of `<commit-specifier>`: if not, fail, if so, continue on to...
2. advance the current branch so that it points to `<commit-specifier>` and read that commit into the index and work-tree (`git read-tree`, the "two tree merge" case—note that this too can fail, if you have uncommitted changes, or untracked files that are in the target commit).

Now, *finding* a specific hash that's *N* commits "ahead of" the current commit in the direction of some target commit can be kind of tricky.  Consider, for instance:

```
...--o--o   <-- master
         \
          \      C--D
           \    /    \
            A--B      G--H   <-- branch
                \    /
                 E--F
```

The tip commit of `branch` is eight commits ahead of the tip commit of `master`—or is it?  I think everyone agrees that `A` is one commit ahead of `master`, and `B` is two ahead.  But what about `C` and `E`, and `D` and `F`?  `C` is three ahead, but so is `E`; and `D` and `F` are both four ahead.  But `G` is not five ahead of `master`: it seems to be *seven* ahead of master.  Likewise, `H` aka `branch` seems to be eight ahead of `master`.

So if I told you to move three commits ahead, would you pick commit `C`, or `E`?  Would you give me an error, or a choice?  Why?

If you constrain things to a linear chain, we can enumerate the commits "between" `master` and `branch`, excluding `master` and including `branch`, with:

```
git rev-list --reverse master..branch
```

and then the *N*-th commit in the list is the commit hash to give to `git merge --ff-only`.  But if there are branch-and-merge chains "between" these two points, the whole question becomes tricky.

Answer (score 0):

As Raymond Chen commented, the solution for the question as *described* is `git merge B`.

I'll leave the question open for a while though in case anyone has a more general answer for the question as *titled*, i.e. for n commits rather than just 1.

Comment: For n commits, you would use `git merge X` where X is n commits ahead of master.